# Doctrine query builder offset changeable

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm a Symfony beginner & I'm trying to load my contact from the database using the Doctrine Query Builder as follows:

**ContactRepository.php**:

```
public function getcontactByLimit($offset, $limit)
{
    $queryBuilder = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('contact')
        ->from($this->_entityName, 'contact')
        ->setFirstResult( $offset )
        ->setMaxResults( $limit )

      $query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();
      $results = $query->getResult();

    return $results;
}
```

**DefaultController.php**:

```
$contacts = $repository->getContactByLimit(0, 3);
```

Now I want to get all contacts I have in the database but just 3 by 3, what means I'm supposed to change the offset value at every loop (to 3 then 6 then 9...)

Have you any idea how to do it ?

Comment: _Now I want to get all contacts I have in the database but just 3 by 3_ Where do you want to get them? you can do `$contactsPage1 = $repository->getContactByLimit(0, 3); $contactsPage2 = $repository->getContactByLimit(3, 3);` but I think is not that you want to achieve.

Comment: A few other things - you're checking for `is_null` on `$offset` and `$limit`, but they are required values in your function and will always be non-null.  Also you're missing a `;` at the end of your `createQueryBuilder()` function

Comment: Yes @Pipe that will not work, as my database is too large (1000 or more).

Comment: @JasonRoman You've right, I've corrected it now thank you, & for the <code>;</code> I don't think that's necessary

Comment: Why don't you fetch all the lines then group them by 3 in a `foreach` loop? Are you trying to create a pagination?

Comment: It's what i'm saying... it's not so clear why you need a group of 3 elements?

Comment: @Pipe 3 by 3 is just an example, it may be more.. but the idea is that I want to devise the database into many parts

Comment: @A.L No it's not for pagination, what I'm trying to do is to send email to my contact lists, so to be able to control the send (pause it or stop it) the contactlist must be few

Comment: Please edit your question and explain your problem more precisely, see [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/237701).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That what I did, & it works fine !

**DefaultController.php:**

```
        $offset = 0;
        $limit = 2;
        $sizeData /= $limit;

        for( $i = 0; $i < $sizeData; $i++)
        {
            $contacts = $repository->getListByLimit($offset, $limit);
            $sender->setContacts($contacts);
            $offset += $limit;
        }
```

**ContactRepository.php:**

```
public function getListByLimit($offset, $limit)
    {
        $queryBuilder = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('contact')
            ->from($this->_entityName, 'contact')
            ->setFirstResult( $offset )
            ->setMaxResults( $limit );

        $query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();
        $results = $query->getResult();
        return $results;
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems for me, that you want to load objects in parts to save memory.

For that, you can use an Iterator:

```
  $query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();
  $iterator = $query->iterate();
  return $iterator;
```

And iterate in your Controller

```
foreach ($iterator as $row) {

}
```

What will happen, is that doctrine uses PDO and select your result but not read it out directly. There is a cursor on the ResultSet of the Database, which is moving on each iteration. So your PHP-Application will get each Row from Database one by one.
To get 3 by 3 packages, you could use the internal position:

```
    $currentPackage = array();
    foreach ($iterator as $position => $row) {
        if($position % 3){
            // do here something with your 3er package before unset
            $currentPackage = array();
            $entityManager->clear(); // clear doctrine, could free memory
        }
        $currentPackage[] = $row;
    }
```

Comment: Nice suggestion on using `iterator()`